# Button does not trigger onClick method

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-button, android-4.4-kitkat

Working on `Android Version - KITKAT`. The problem persists when `Button - newRide` does not trigger `onClick()` method, the same code works very well on other `Android Version > KITKAT`.

Java Code Snippet from My Class:

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_ongoing_ride_details, null, false);
    View cView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.title_bar, null);

    imgSignOut = (ImageView) cView.findViewById(R.id.imgSignout);
    imgRefresh = (ImageView) cView.findViewById(R.id.imgRefresh);
    tvTitle = (TextView) cView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
    newRide = (Button)contentView.findViewById(R.id.btnNewRide);

    if (Utilities.getStringFromPrefs(getApplicationContext(), "userType")
        .equals("driver")) {
        setContentView(contentView);
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setCustomView(cView);

        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(
            new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#ffffff")));
        tvTitle.setText("ON GOING RIDES");
        tvTitle.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    } 
    else {
        frameLayout.addView(contentView);

        getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM
            | android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP);
        getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_title);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_drawer);
        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
            new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#ffffff")));
        TextView headTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytext);
        headTxt.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        headTxt.setText("ON GOING RIDES");

    }

    lvRideList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvRideDetails);
    llNoBookings = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llNoBookings);

    HsApi = new APIImple();
    onGoingRideResult = new ArrayList<OnGoingRideDetails>();
    mTask = new GetOnGoingRideDetails().execute();

    if (!(Utilities.getStringFromPrefs(getApplicationContext(), "userType")
        .equals("driver"))) {

        newRide.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        newRide.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (!Utilities.isConnected(getApplicationContext())) {
                    Utilities.notConnectedToast(getApplicationContext());

                } else {
                    Intent in = new Intent(OnGoingRideDetailsList.this,
                        FragmentActivity.class);
                    startActivity(in);
                }
            }


        });
    } 
    else {
        newRide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNewRide);
        newRide.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

 lvRideList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (onGoingRideResult.get(position).getUserType()
                .equals("driver")) {
                Intent intentToDriverScreen = new Intent(
                    OnGoingRideDetailsList.this,
                    DriverWelcomeScreen.class);
                intentToDriverScreen.putExtra("rideData",
                    onGoingRideResult.get(position));
                startActivity(intentToDriverScreen);
            } 
            else {
                Intent intentToUserRideScreen = new Intent(
                    OnGoingRideDetailsList.this,
                    UserCurrentBookings.class);
                intentToUserRideScreen.putExtra("rideData",
                    onGoingRideResult.get(position));
                startActivity(intentToUserRideScreen);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

XML `activity_ongoing_ride_details.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/bgcolor"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnNewRide"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/mybutton_bg"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:text="Click here for New Ride"
    android:textColor="@color/buttontextcolor"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:visibility="visible"/>


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvRideDetails"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="#c8c8c8"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:focusable="false"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llNoBookings"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Sorry! No Active Bookings Available for you"
        android:textColor="#ff9966"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/sadsmiley"/>
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not recognize"?

Comment: onclick event was not working

Comment: add `newRide = (Button) cView.findViewById(R.id.btnNewRide);` before the `newRide` visibility code.

Comment: @W4R10CK yea i already mentioned this but button onclick was not working..:(

Comment: where did you added your button `findViewById` code ? add before making it in `onClickListener`

Comment: @W4R10CK I added below to the tvTitle variable

Comment: use `cView` not `contentView`

Comment: @W4R10CK my code works fine in all version devices good but in kitkat version the button onclick was not working

Comment: @W4R10CK I'm fine with helping OP. Just do it here. There's no need to have multiples of the same question. Honestly, I only left this question last time after I saw that OP was getting help from you folks.

Comment: @MikeM., I agree.

Comment: @HsRaja, Please add your brief java code along with XML.

Comment: @HsRaja If you want to bump this question, simply edit it - e.g., to emphasize that you're having a problem on KitKat specifically. Then, everybody watching the active queue will see it again, too.

Comment: @W4R10CK Thanks i will post here

Comment: @MikeM. yea i will do

Comment: In else of if (!(Utilities.getStringFromPrefs(getApplicationContext(), "userType")
    .equals("driver"))) why are you adding this code newRide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNewRide); Remove this line and check.

Comment: Just from a quick look through the layout, if you're certain that `newRide.setOnClickListener()` is getting called, then my first suggestion would be to move the `btnNewRide` `<Button>` to the end of the layout XML, right before the closing `</RelativeLayout>` tag. If you want it clickable, it should be on top of everything else, z-order-wise.

Comment: @MikeM. yea i formatted as you said

Comment: @MikeM. Hurray!!!!!Thanks man you saved me!!!!

Comment: Oh, good. I was just copying and pasting your code to test on a KitKat device, and it was gonna be a real pain to fill in all the missing stuff. No hard feelings? I'm just trying to help moderate the site, keep things tidy, easier to find stuff, when I close questions like that. It's nothing personal. Anyhoo, glad you got it working. Cheers!

Comment: @MikeM. yea i got bit frustrated initially but..you are doing a great job !!! cheers man!!

Comment: @MikeM. Finally no more repeated questions and closing. I was about to start a bounty on it. :)

Comment: @HsRaja, Thanks to me man, I updated your code like pro.. haha :)

Comment: @W4R10CK Fantastic man!! you are  again and again proving that you are pro!!! haha ;)

Comment: @MikeM. 1 just confusion, what made the button layout not trigger. Means why the button should be on last of the layout any specific reason ?

Comment: @W4R10CK The z-order of `View`s inflated from a layout is determined by the order in which they're added to the parent. In the posted layout, the `Button`, listed first, would be "on the bottom"; i.e., farther away on the axis perpendicular to the screen. Also, in a `RelativeLayout`, `View`s can overlap, cover other `View`s. You can see that the `ListView` fills the `RelativeLayout`, so odds were good that it was intercepting touch events before they got to the `Button` underneath. The fact that the behavior varied depending on the version is just due to how things change from one to the next.

Comment: @Mike M. Well explained!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (!(Utilities.getStringFromPrefs(getApplicationContext(), "userType")
    .equals("driver")))
```

I think that the problem is in this statement. This condition is not true

Comment: That's not a problem i am getting clear log in that..perfect

Comment: Can you post your layout... It is possible that your button is hidden by some another view.

Comment: send xml layout here

Comment: my code works fine in all version devices good but in kitkat version the button onclick was not working

Comment: In else, why are you adding this code newRide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNewRide); ?

Comment: @mdg5435 yea if i removed that line its facing same issue in kitkat